# custom calculation with results being in Currency format

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat, calculated-field

I am making a [PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OaIMbFq57LjJ-go0-Pz7t9VOBSOpD5kb) with a custom calculation script and I want to get the product of 2 fields with the results in the format of currency and for the life of me I cant figure it out. I am relatively new to a lot of this.

Here is the code I currently have:

```js
var QtyRow1 = (this.getField( "QtyRow1").value); // the value of QtyRow1;
var CostRow1 = (this.getField( "CostRow1").value); // the value of CostRow1;

var t1 = QtyRow1 * CostRow1; // the value all TotalRows;

if ( t1 < .01 ) {
     // t1 will remain blank if total of CostRow1 * QtyRow are less than 1;
    event.value = "";
}  else {
    // otherwise will calculate total of all TotalRows;        
    event.value = t1;     
}
```

Additionally here is a link to my PDF I am working on from my google drive. I am trying to take the Quantity and Cost of each row and so a total in the format of Currency from the product of the quantity and cost.

Comment: I'm not sure that this relates to Java programming

Comment: Adobe PDF Custom Scripts use Javascript.

Comment: Right, but again what does that have to do with ***Java***? You do know that the two languages are vastly different, about as similar as ham and hamster, and you want to make sure to use the right program language question tags, else you will attract the wrong experts to your question, reducing your chances of getting help or answers.

Comment: Ahhhh, Okay yeah I didnt know that. LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was I wasn't identifying t1 as a number format with in the JavaScript code so when I would go to the format tab under the form field properties and select that I wanted it to formatted to number and currency it wouldn't work cause it would give me an error saying the "t1" hasn't been properly formatted. So all I did was within the if statement made sure to tell JavaScript that t1 needed to be formatted to a number and did so by doing this: event.value = (Number(t1)) as to where before I just had event.value = t1. That fixed it and now everything works great.

Here is a link to the new PDF with the new code in it:
[Click Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OaIMbFq57LjJ-go0-Pz7t9VOBSOpD5kb)

```js
// the value of form field QtyRow1;
var QtyRow1 = (this.getField("QtyRow1").value);

// the value of form field CostRow1;
var CostRow1 = (this.getField("CostRow1").value);

// the product of form fields QtyRow1 and CostRow1;
var t1 = QtyRow1 * CostRow1; 

// if statement for results
  if( t1 < .01 )
{
// t1 will remain blank if total of form fields CostRow1 * QtyRow are less than .01;
  event.value = ""; 

  } else {

// otherwise will caclculate the product of form fields QtyRow1 and CostRow1;
  event.value = (Number(t1));
}
```